# python subprocess with tableau tabcmd error

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tableau-api

I am trying to access tableau via tabcmd on linux box using python script:

```
  tabcmd= "login -s " + taburl + " -u " + tabuser+ " --password-file " + '"' + tabpwpath + '"' + " --no-certcheck" #specify your cmd command
  print(tabcmd)
  cmdCommand =  tabcmd_path + tabcmd
  print("check " + cmdCommand)
  process= subprocess.check_output(cmdCommand,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

The cmdCommand being passed is constructed like this:

```
/opt/tableau/tabcmd/bin/tabcmd login -s http://tableau.server.com -u username --password-file "/home/user/testpw.file" --no-certcheck
```

When I run this command in linux manually it works, but when use subprocess it gives error like:

```
process= subprocess.check_output([cmdCommand],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 376, in check_output
**kwargs).stdout
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 453, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
 File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
 File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1499, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Why subprocess don't recognize the same way as running manually with extact same print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the difference is between windows and linux:

```
process = subprocess.check_output(cmdCommand, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
```

I added the shell true and in linux it works perfectly